# How to change font size of text in HTML file loaded using UIWebView in iPhone

Tags: html, objective-c, css, ios5

I have 20 HTML files.. All those files are in my bundle... For example the font size of text in HTML file is 15... That size is enough for iPhone but For iPad it is looking very small... How can i change the font size of text in HTML file dynamically using iPhone code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at CSS media queries. You can apply different font sizes (and other CSS properties) depending on the physical attributes of the device, in your case the `min-width` and `max-width` attributes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 799px)" /> this is Exact Answer